# sign PowerShell and .DLL remotely

Tags: powershell, code-signing

Scenario:

- as development team member I create some .dll files and .ps1 files
- I'm trusted that I produced correct code
- I'm required to sign those files but security team is in charge of signing certificates
- I could just send them all my binaries and wait for them to return signed
- ... but I produce quite huge .zip archive ...

So I'm thinking if there is a way to save us all this sending binaries back and forth.

Question:

Is that possible that I generate any SHA-1 / SHA-256 / MD5 / whatever hashes from all my files, then I send those to security team, they generate signatures, send them back and I attach them to original files.

Comment: No, it's not possible, not for `*.ps1` files anyway. The signing API needs access to both the certificate/key and the whole input file at the same time

Comment: I've been searching for any documentation regarding this but I didn't find. Are you able to confirm it with any documentation?

Comment: No, I had a look at the source code for `Set-AuthenticodeSignature`, it calls [CryptUIWizDigitalSign](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/cryptuiapi/nf-cryptuiapi-cryptuiwizdigitalsign), to which you need to pass a struct that has been initialized with a handle to the cert + the file

Comment: Why not just use a common network share that you build into, and your security team has access to?  Seems inefficient that you must copy/send the files for signing.